# How to use the new gpt-3.5-16k model with langchain?

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

I have written an application in langchain that passes a number of chains to a Sequential Chain to run.  The problem I'm having is that the prompts are so large that they are exceeding the 4K token limit size.  I saw that OpenAI has released a new 16K token window sized model for ChatGPT, but I can't seem to access it from the API.  When I try, I get the following error:

openai.error.InvalidRequestError: This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint. Did you mean to use v1/chat/completions?

Here is how I'm attempting to instantiate the model:

```
  self.llm = OpenAI(model='gpt-3.5-turbo-16k',temperature = self.config.llm.temperature,
                          openai_api_key = self.config.llm.openai_api_key,         
                          max_tokens=self.config.llm.max_tokens                 
                         )
```

Anybody know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 7):

### Update 20th Auguest, 2023

[OpenAIChat is deprecated.](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/1556) Use [ChatOpenAI()](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/models/chat/) model instead. Also one side note, the model name should pass through the `model_name` parameter.

```py
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

chat = ChatOpenAI(
    model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo-16k',
    temperature = self.config.llm.temperature,
    openai_api_key = self.config.llm.openai_api_key,         
    max_tokens=self.config.llm.max_tokens
)
```

---

#### Old Answer:

The `gpt-3.5-turbo-16k` is supposed to be used with the chat completion API endpoint. See the [ref](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/how-we-use-your-data) below:

| ENDPOINT | MODEL NAME |
| --- | --- |
| /v1/chat/completions | gpt-4, gpt-4-0613, gpt-4-32k, gpt-4-32k-0613, gpt-3.5-turbo, gpt-3.5-turbo-0613, gpt-3.5-turbo-16k, gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613 |
| /v1/completions | text-davinci-003, text-davinci-002, text-curie-001, text-babbage-001, text-ada-001 |

So, instead of using the `OpenAI()` llm, which uses text completion API under the hood, try using `OpenAIChat()`. See the below example with ref to your sample code:

```py
from langchain.llms import OpenAIChat

self.llm = OpenAIChat(
    model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo-16k',
    temperature = self.config.llm.temperature,
    openai_api_key = self.config.llm.openai_api_key,         
    max_tokens=self.config.llm.max_tokens                 
)
```

Comment: I get ImportError: cannot import name 'OpenAIChat' from 'langchain.llms' when I try this

Comment: OpenAIChat is deprecated. Use ChatOpenAI() model instead. See my updated answer. @megmac

Answer (score 2):

```
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0.1, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k")
```

Works fine for me.